# Why would a God (who can bring back or look after the dead) have a reason to think murder is wrong?

Tags: ethics, theology, moral-skepticism

Apologists for various religions often say murder is obviously wrong. That often tracks if you imagine from the perspective of a human. However, I don't see how that could **possibly** be what a God would think.

---

To illustrate my point, the often given example is would you be okay with your child being murdered. If you imagine a human's perspective, then the general conclusion is it is not okay.

However, God can just bring humans back to life.

If **I** could bring my loved ones back to life or just go to the world of the dead to speak with them, my loved ones being murdered would not bother me, as long as they did not get too hurt.

In movies where loved ones die and get revived, do you expect their loved ones to throw a funeral and grieve like they died for good? Would you be perplexed as to why anyone would react to their loved ones temporarily dying, even while they weren't watching, the same way as permeant death?

---

I know some humans think that life is a gift from God, however, by that logic shouldn't death be too?

---

As for rules for society, it does not make sense either, as society cannot really murder itself to death, as humans would form self protecting gangs. Even if a lot of humans die, so what? You can just revive them.

---

The point is, far from being obvious murder is wrong from God's perspective, the only perspective that should count, it doesn't seem to make **any** sense.

---

Has anyone relevant explained why they think **God** should think murder is wrong? *Other than just saying: "Look, the humans think it is wrong." as if that proves anything.*

(Similar issues exist for many common human morals from God's perspective)

Comment: I think it's like the prohibition from boiling a baby goat in it's mother's milk, you're not supposed to ask because God is perfect and you're not. Also God does not intervene so as to let us have free will (except when He does, of course, but bare with me) because otherwise the notion of sin would be meaningless. So the argument that He could always right the wrong we do does not work. He could always unboil the baby goat but by doing so He would deprive us of our ability to do wrong.

Comment: Following this logic, rape isn't wrong because the woman can always get an abortion.

Comment: Heavily opinion-based, a lot of subjective assumptions and opinions: God "thinks"; "God can just bring humans back to life"; "life is a gift from God"; "murder is wrong from God's perspective"; "issues exist for many common human morals from God's perspective"...

Comment: God makes makes it wrong for *humans* to kill, not for himself, and *humans* cannot bring the dead back to life. If *they* could things might be different, it isn't wrong to raze a house and build a new one, for example. God does not make it his business to clean up after humans, that is the point of free will, *they* are to deal with the consequences of *their own* actions. How else would they be autonomous beings rather than just his playthings?

Comment: @DavidGudeman Still get the trauma

Comment: @Conifold Why even care?

Comment: @Aseku Vena-Have you consider that "He who murders is "playing God"? And God alone has that prerogative ? The only One who has the wisdom (and sense of justice) to handle life and death matters?

Answer (score 3):

This question would be considerably better without dancing robot emojis. Also not sure whether Philosophy SE is supposed to extend to comparative religion, but this is an easy enough question to answer succinctly, so:

In the Judaism and Christianity, murder is an act of *blasphemy* because God created humans in his own image (Genesis 9:5-6). Questions of whether God can bring back the deceased or whether doing so would be better or worse than leaving them dead would thus be irrelevant to the principle sin, which is the intentional and unnecessary destruction of an image of God.

In Islam, murder is *sacrilege* (arguably identical to the Judeo-Christian position) because God has made human life* sacred (Quran 6:151); and of *theft* (Quran 4:29). Again, the possibility and morality of resurrection would thus be irrelevant to the principle sins, which are the unjustified destruction of something sacred and the unjust taking of somebody else's property.

*Or *some* human lives, depending on your reading. I don't read or speak Arabic and I haven't studied any scholars of the text, which I've read translated variously as "take not life, which God hath made sacred" and "do not kill the soul sanctified by God".

Comment: But why does he care?